# Is the clipboard shared between desktops under Windows?

Tags: windows, security, clipboard, desktop

MSDN says:

> A window station contains a clipboard, an atom table, and one or more
>   desktop objects.

According to above, both of the winlogon desktop and the current desktop are belong to WinSta0; so they should share the same clipboard of WinSta0.

However, if you copy a piece of text in the current desktop, say "abcd", and press Ctrl + Alt + Del to switch to the winlogon desktop, then try to paste the text to the password box; you will not succeed!

Why?

Comment: The logon desktop is special, it is a *secure* desktop.  Hardened by a good 30 years of people trying to break into Windows machines.  The exact countermeasures that Microsoft implemented are not public knowledge, for obvious reasons.  But yeah, don't expect Ctrl+V to do much.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to paste, Ctrl+V? I'm guessing that Winlogon just doesn't support copy/paste. You can confirm this by trying to copy/paste part of your username (in the change password screen)

Comment: Yes, Ctrl+V, sorry, not Ctrl+C.  But also, I have no pop-up menu.